# Drupal auto upload excel by cron

Tags: files

How can I upload a number of excel files by a cron, with no need to browse and upload from the user interface? I have already made it, but I want these file to be automatically uploaded to a particular table on a cron run or on a single click.

Comment: What have you already done ? And are these excel files manually created or fetched from 3rd party site ?

Comment: you can't upload files using cron to Drupal database, however you can use cron to store the files path or store the files as binary in the database